# Convert input image to Base64 using VueJs and typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, vue.js, frontend, base64

This is my first question here.

I would like to convert an input file(image) from a form using VueJs 3 and typescript to Base64 to "send" it to my backend (java, spring boot) and store it in mongodb as a part of a "User" model

Here's what I have:

The line e.target.files[0] keeps saying that it's possibly null.. so the const selectedImage and this.picture won't get them.

```
<template>
<v-file-input
  @change="handleImage"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  label="File input"
  v-model="picture"
  filled
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
></v-file-input>
</template>
```

```
<script lang="ts">
interface State {
picture: string;
}

data: (): State => {
return {
picture: "",
  }
}
methods: {
handleImage(e: Event) {
      const selectedImage = e.target.files[0];
      this.createBase64Image(selectedImage);
    },
    createBase64Image(fileObject: File) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.picture = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileObject);
    },
},
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I downvoted this because it is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You could change **reader.readAsBinaryString(fileObject)** in the *createBase64Image* function to **reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)**

Also something that would help is to use refs in your component

```
<template>
<v-file-input
  @change="handleImage"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  label="File input"
  v-model="picture"
  filled
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  ref="file"
></v-file-input>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
interface State {
picture: string;
}

data: (): State => {
return {
picture: "",
  }
}
methods: {
    handleImage(e: Event) {
      const selectedImage = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      this.picture = this.createBase64Image(selectedImage);
    },
    createBase64Image(fileObject: File) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      return reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject);
    },
},
</script>
```

Additional Information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: I tried that too. But the error keeps showing. e.target.result is possibly null

Comment: Update my answer, I hope you find it useful. Don't forget to vote for me.

Comment: I don't understand why your component needs a v-model, but if you just want to output the result in base64 just send it in your request.

Comment: still have the problem?

Comment: Still null. Yep.
I set the e to any type (e: any) and now it doesn't complain. I'll see if it works and sends the image to the backend

Comment: this.$refs.file.files[0] doesn't work. It says the type is unknown.. I've got the ref="file" inside the v-file-input tag but don't know how..it doesn't get it. I'm kinda desperate...

Comment: It could help if you put an example with the minimum functional line to be able to see the code

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION HERE: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-upload-base64-images-in-vue-nodejs-4e89635daebc

Answer (score 0):

I think onchange event doesn't guarantees e.target.result to be non-null. Do this check:

```
if (e.target && e.target.files.length > 0)
```